# I'm trying to get average rides by hour weekday vs weekend

Tags: r, count, weekday, weekend

https://www.kaggle.com/timothypalmer/divvy-capstone-project/edit

I know there is a better way, but I'm new at this.
I have hourly output aggregated, but I need to

1. separate data by weekday/weekend
2. get average rides per day

   - divide weekday output by 5
   - divide weekend output by 2

I've looked at ways to do this separately, but I think there should be a way I can do this side by side.  I think I need to make 2 separate new variables, average_rides_weekend, average_rides_weekday and then graph them somehow.  Newbie issues.

```
rides_by_hour <- data_year3%>% 
  group_by(start_hour, member_casual, is_weekend) %>% 
  summarise(number_of_rides = n(), .groups = 'drop') 
  
ggplot(data = rides_by_hour) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = start_hour, y = number_of_rides, fill = member_casual), stat='identity', position = "dodge") + 
  facet_wrap(~is_weekend, labeller = labeller(is_weekend = days.labs)) + 
  labs(title="Number of rides for casual and member riders during a day",
       x="Hours during a day",
       y="Number of rides", subtitle="Aug2022 to July2023") + 
  theme(legend.position="top") + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Rider: ")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Tim Palmer! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: (More specifically, please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].)

Comment: Sorry.  This is my first post.  I'm working with R in Kaggle to aggregate millions of lines of data, so I posting a sample data set is difficult.  I'll copy the code into the comments.

Comment: I included a hyperlink to my project.  It's opensource data, so anyone can look at it.  Sorry that it's a kind of a mess, but you're welcome to look.  I removed the picture, as well.

Comment: Including a picture of the output is fine, so long as it adds perspective or context. For instance, providing the output from `dput(.)` for sample data is great for many reasons, but it's really hard to "see" it, so it is fine to include a pic of it along side the `structure(...)` expression. Sometimes it adds context/perspective, which is why I asked *"do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors"*.

Comment: Your kaggle link returns 404 for me.

Comment: The kaggle link wasn't public, I guess.  Please try again.

Comment: When it becomes problematic sharing data (difficulty, proprietary, just too big, etc), an alternative is to look at one of the public datasets to see what looks somewhat like what I'm trying to do (time-series, multi-facets, whatever), and then using that. Since you're using `ggplot2`, you can perhaps start with one of `data(package="ggplot2")`, though you also have richer datasets like `iris`, `dplyr::starwars`, and many others. I know it's extra work for you to adapt your problem to different data, but ... sometimes trying to do that helps you self-resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm willing to work with that other dataset.  The whole point of this is to learn how to deal with the data.  I will accept any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to the community, as r2evans mentioned a reproducible example will helps us to see your data and try your code and then provide you with the working code.

Also you kaggle notebook is private so we can't see it, if you can go to settings and change it to public we will be able to have a look at it.

However from what I understand the below code would help you and provide you with the output you need. I didn't check the rest of ggplot code so I kept it as it is.

```
rides_by_hour <- data_year3%>% 
  group_by(start_hour, is_weekend) %>% 
  summarise(avg_rides = mean(column name for rides), .groups = 'drop') 

## this will create an avg rides column for weekend and weekdays for each start_hour
  
ggplot(data = rides_by_hour) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = start_hour, y = avg_rides, fill = member_casual), stat='identity', position = "dodge") + 
  facet_wrap(~is_weekend, labeller = labeller(is_weekend = days.labs)) + 
  labs(title="Number of rides for casual and member riders during a day",
       x="Hours during a day",
       y="Number of rides", subtitle="Aug2022 to July2023") + 
  theme(legend.position="top") + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Rider: ")
```

Comment: The kaggle notebook is now public, OP fixed that part :-)

Comment: Thanks for verifying that the notebook is viewable.  I'm still working on this, but I'm probably just going to separate the data into weekday/ weekend datasets and divide separately.  There is a way to do it together, I'm sure.

Comment: Ok dear great, I have now access to it, I will check and let you know shortly.